# Obtaining key from Join Table in a Sequelize include

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm working in Node JS and Sequelize/MySQL. I have two tables Agent and Neighborhood as well as a join table AgentNeighborhood. I'd like, when querying these tables to obtain the join table key.

AgentNeighborhood

```
const AgentNeighborhood = sequelize.define('agentneighborhood', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    agent_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      required: true,
      references: {
        model: 'Agent',
        key: 'id'
      },
      allowNull: false
    },
    neighborhood_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      required: true,
      references: {
        model: 'Neighborhood',
        key: 'id'
      },
      allowNull: false
    },
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscore: true
  })
```

Neighborhood

```
const Neighborhood = sequelize.define('neighborhood', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ...
    ...
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
  })

  Neighborhood.associate = (models) => {
    Neighborhood.belongsToMany(models.agent, { through: 'agentneighborhood', foreignKey: 'neighborhood_id' })
  }
```

Agent

```
const Agent = sequelize.define('agent', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ....
},
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
  })

  Agent.associate = (models) => {
    Agent.belongsToMany(models.neighborhood, { through: 'agentneighborhood', foreignKey: 'agent_id' })
  }
```

How can I query the keys so that my result will be as follows ?

```
{
  id // the primary key for the AgentNeighborhood table
  agent_id
  agent {
    id // should be same as agent_id
     ...
  }
  neighborhood_id
  neighborhood {
    id // should be same as neighborhood_id
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried the following but get an error that neighborhood is not associated to agentneighborhood.

```
const agentneighborhoods = await models.agentneighborhood.findAll({where: {agent_id: 1}, include: [
            {model: models.neighborhood},
            {model: models.agent},
          ]})
          return agentneighborhoods
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to get list of neighbors associated with that agent_id.

```
const agentneighborhoods= await models.neighbors.findAll({
    where: { "$agentneighborhood.agent_id$": agent_id },
       include: [
       {
         as: "agentneighborhood",
         model: models.agentneighborhood,
         required: true
       }
      ]
   });

 return agentneighborhoods
```

Comment: Thanks Amir. When I do this, I still get the message that the model agentneighborhood is not associated with neighbor. Perhaps I need to explicitly define an association between the junction table and each side of the many-to-many relationship. My ultimate goal is to be able to return the ID of the junction table entry for my findAll query so that if I wanted to update the junction table, I have the ID handy.